# Login and Sign up in the home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise

I recently started working with Ruby on Rails and using the Devise gem for authentications. Worked fine for me, when I started a new app to try the Devise Gem. However, the template I'm using has both the Log in and Sign up forms on the Home page. Since Devise create two new views, I won't be needing them, and I will have to move these two views code to my home.html.erb file.

The issue I'm having is, after following [these steps](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Display-a-custom-sign_in-form-anywhere-in-your-app), the form is created, and I fill in the username and password, but pressing the submit button does absolutely nothing. Furthermore, there are three links created under the submit bottom; login, signup, and forgot password, that redirect me to the pages that Devise creates, the same pages I am trying to avoid.

I've looked in many places, but with no luck. I have a one week experience with RoR and two days experience with the Devise Gem, so I must be doing something ridiculously dumb. Any help?

Here is the sign-in form that I copied over to my home.html.erb file

```
    <%= form_for("user", :url => user_session_path) do |f| %>
    <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email, :autofocus => true %></div>
    <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password %></div>
    <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
    <% end -%>
    <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
    <% end %>
    <%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

And here is my application helper file:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def resource_name
    :user
  end

  def resource
    @resource ||= User.new
  end

  def devise_mapping
    @devise_mapping ||= Devise.mappings[:user]
  end

end
```

and my config/routes.rb file:

```
  devise_for :users
  root 'pages#home'
```

**EDIT suggested routes.rb**

```
  get "pages/home"
  devise_for :users

  devise_scope :users do
  get "pages/home", :to => "devise/sessions#new"
  post "/users/sign_in", :to => "devise/sessions#create", :as => :sign_in
  end
```

Still, no result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure how your routes are setup but if you want to display a custom sign-in/sign-up view and have it direct you to the appropriate place you'll need to make sure you change the scope of the devise routes and direct them to your custom views/routes.

For example, if you wanted to change your post route for signing up (after you hit submit) you might have something like this:

```
devise_scope :user do
  get "/home", :to => "devise/sessions#new", :as => :home 
  post "/users/sign_up", :to => "devise/sessions#create", :as => :sign_up
end
```

I just made up the name spacing for your purposes but it might be different.

It would be worth while to take a look at the Devise documentation which describes in more detail how to change default sign-in and sign-up routes [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Change-the-default-sign_in-and-sign_out-routes)

Hope this helps.

## **EDIT:**

After looking at this further, though the information above will be helpful to you, I think what actually might be your problem is that you are missing :user on your first line of the form_for.  Try doing this instead:

```
<%= form_for(:user, :url => user_session_path(:user)) do |f| %>
```

This is how its shown at the link I provided above.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I edited my question adding my routes.rb file, and I edited that line in my home.html.erb file. 
I tried your suggestion, now the home page shows me ONLY the Devise log in basic form. So basically, this changed the URL of the sign in from: /users/sign_in to /pages/home. What happened to my home view?

Comment: Sorry the result in my previous comment is wrong, I have updated my routes.rb in the question as you suggested, but the result is the same as before. Login form in my template, nothing happens when hitting the submit button.